# Deleting part of a stored JSON object in Laravel

Tags: php, json, database, api, laravel

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to remove an index in a stored JSON array without having to store the object locally and remove it.

```
{
name: example,
data: [{id: 1, value: foo}, {id: 2, value:bar}],
color: red
}
```

Can I make a query like:

```
DB::table('db')->where('name', '=', example)->where('data.id', '=', 2)-> delete();
```

Comment: Is it about `json` field in mysql 5.7+ ?

Comment: Yes - is is a `json` field in the sql row

Comment: i think that you can not do it with eloquent at now. You can replace it with empty in raw sql. Eloquent will give much better support for this column type in Laravel 5.3